# How can I mirror one iPhone 4 to another?

Tags: iphone

I have heard you can mirror an iPhone 4 so that whatever happens on one phone you will see on the mirrored phone. Can this really be done and if so how do I go about setting up the two phones? I am very technologicaly challenged, but I'd like to monitor my daughter's iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Without jailbreak, No.

With jailbreak, still, No.

Furthermore, it is considered pretty rude to do that IF it's for spying on someone.